# Elasticsearch - is there a method to match using "almost ident"

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, elasticsearch, geolocation, elasticsearch-net

I use Facebook and Google maps to get a full Geo Entities data values (country, city, street, zip...).

I store these values  on my mongoDB,

I noticed that some locations are deffer in the way they were written on Face and on Google, for (an unreal) example Face wrote the name of 'Hawaii' with an 'e' - Haweii.

I use match_all fields (country + city + street...) to search for entities at the same location but since some are written a bit different i will not find them.

Is there a way make elasticsearch search for 'Hawaii' **and** any other option that sounds like Hawaii but written a bit different?

Thanks for any help!

Using Google API one can get a [location's](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/205+New+York+Ave,+Newark,+NJ+07105,+USA/@40.72584,-74.1631377,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c253998a75ff21:0x25152995bf2e5423!8m2!3d40.72584!4d-74.160949?hl=en)
 full details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match words that sound similar you can use the [phonetic analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html). You can also give [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) a try to match words with spelling mistakes. None of them are fool proof though and may result in false positives. Guess you'll have to experiment a little to come up with a solution that best fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known set of differences between Facebook and Google maps, you could look at [using Synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html) at either index time or query time to accommodate differences in the APIs; [There are merits to taking either approach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms-expand-or-contract.html).